# What is the purpose of a .cmake file?

Tags: cmake

I might be googling wrongly, but I'm unable to find what's the purpose of .cmake files.

I've just stumbled across the CMake tool for a project I've to work with and I'm having a hard time to understand how it works. I do understand that running the CMake command in a directory containing a `CMakeLists.txt` executes the commands in that file (along with the commands in the `CMakeLists.txt` contained in the sub-directories) but the purpose of .cmake files is a lot more fuzzy.

It seems that they are used to define functions/set variables that are thereafter used in the `CMakeLists.txt` but I'm not sure. How are they used by the CMake tool ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can include it with the include command. Similar to how other languages allow you to split source files into modules or header files, they can contain function definitions, macros which can then be reused across multiple CmakeLists.

See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include.html

Note that you can actually include any file, but a .cmake extension is commonly used.

Comment: Further to this, often .cmake files are bundled with modules to provide some  scriptable functionality. Often called via the `-P ...` mechanism.

Comment: I am not quite sure that all .cmake files are always include files, some of them seem to be executed like scripts. For example in a build I'm doing with Visual Studio, it calls `cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=$(Configuration) -P cmake_install.cmake`. Is a .cmake file kind of assumed to be an internal file (i.e., one that's generated by a script rather than one that you edit directly?), though that theory doesn't hold, either, because CMakeCache has the extension .txt.

Answer (score 16):

Within this file you can define functions of macros which can be used in your CMakeLists.txt file. But there are some more other applications for .cmake files. For example if you want to provide a library or tool they should at least contain a `<name>Config.cmake` so that your library can be used with the `find_package()` command. Further information can be found in [CMake Wiki](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-to-create-a-ProjectConfig.cmake-file)

Answer (score 3):

> CMake input files are written in the "CMake Language" in source files named `CMakeLists.txt` or ending in a `.cmake` file name extension.
> https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html

This means they're one and the same thing. "CMakeLists.txt" is simply the default name. If you decide to split the code (CMake is technically just another interpreted language) into separate files/modules (that you can `include` into each other), they obviously can't all have the same name, so you would use the ".cmake" extension. Theoretically, you could call "CmakeLists.txt" as "CmakeLists.cmake", but then cmake won't be able to find it by default, so you'd have to pass the filename as a command-line argument. So it is just a difference of naming conventions. Everything you can put in one file, you can put in the other, and vice-versa.